# React - JS variables not updating properly on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, count

I made this button handle function, when clicked it will check the entered character against the stored "hangman" word.

- If the letter exists in the string it shows its correct and increase
  "guesses"
- If it isn't present it will increase both "guesses" and "incorrect"List item
- If the letter has already been tried or contains "" / " " it will do
  nothing

However the functionality is acting strange, initially putting in "a" will show that it is not currently stored, the lives is default yet the guesses is still 0, it is not updating guesses.

Then inputting "b" shows it is not stored and incorrect. However it does not add a value to incorrect.

Inserting "b" on the next input shows it is stored. However correctly displays lives.

Lastly this functionality doesnt seem to work at all when removing the

This functionality just seems really strange to me. Not sure where i am going wrong

Console output:

```
Objecthint: 
hint: "the start of something"
id: 1
title: "initial"
value: 1
word: "initial"

Hangman.js:62 not stored
Hangman.js:77 lives5
Hangman.js:78 guesses0
Hangman.js:79 incorrect0

Hangman.js:72 not stored and incorrect
Hangman.js:77 lives5
Hangman.js:78 guesses1
Hangman.js:79 incorrect0

Hangman.js:52 stored
Hangman.js:77 lives4
Hangman.js:78 guesses1
Hangman.js:79 incorrect1
```

code:

```
    const [letter, setLetter]=useState('')
    const [letters, setLetters]=useState([])
    const [guesses, setGuesses]=useState(0)
    const [incorrect, setIncorrect]=useState(0)
    const [lives, setLives]=useState(5)

    var hangman = { id:1,title:"initial",word:"initial",hint:"the start of something",value:1}
 
    const handleInputButton = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (letter !== "" && letter !== " "){
            if (letters.includes(letter))
            {
                console.log("stored")
                // show that this letter is correct
            }

            // doesnt update lives when incorrect until second click of same character? 
            else{
                if ( hangman.word.toUpperCase().includes(letter.toUpperCase()) ) {

                    console.log("not stored")
                    letters.push(letter)
                    setGuesses(guesses + 1)
                    // update display here
                }
                else{
                    letters.push(letter)
                    setIncorrect(incorrect + 1)
                    setLives(lives - 1 )
                    console.log("not stored and incorrect")
                }

            }
        }
        console.log("lives" + lives)
        console.log("guesses" +guesses)
        console.log("incorrect" + incorrect)
    }

    const [Attempt, setAttempt] =([]);
    const handleSubmitButton = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("submit")
         // put request here to post
    }
    
    const handleHint = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // reveal hint text here
        console.log("hint")
    }

        return (
            <div className='app'>
                <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>

                {/* display will go here */}
                <img alt="hangman figure"/>

                <br/> <br/>
                {/* current lives will go here */}
                <p> lives: {lives} </p>

                {/* attempted letters will go here */}
                <ul> attempted letters:
                {letters.map(letter=>( 
                            <li className="tag auto" key={letters.indexOf(letter)}> <p> {letter} </p> </li>
                        ))}
                </ul>

                <Form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input value={letter} onChange={(e)=>setLetter(e.target.value)}
                                type="text" className="form-control stuff" id="letter" placeholder="Enter Letter" required/>
                        </div>

                        <br/> <br/>

                        <Button onClick={handleInputButton} type="buton" className="btn btn-primary submit" id="submit">Submit</Button>
                </Form>

                <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>
                {/* hint button */}
                <Button>Hint</Button> 
                <p> {hangman.hint} </p>
                <br/> <br/>
                {/* finalise button */}
                <Button onClick={handleSubmitButton} type="buton" className="btn btn-primary submit" id="submit">Finalize</Button>
               
                {/* {showResult ? (
                <div className='result'>
                    Your result is {result} of {questionList.length}
                </div>
                ) : (
                <>
                    <div className='question'>
                    <div className='index'>
                        <span>Question {current + 1}</span>/{questionList.length}
                    </div>
                    <div className='text' onCopy={handleCopy} >{questionList[current].question}</div>
                    </div>

                    <div className='answer-section'>
                    {questionList[current].answers.map((answer, index) => (
                        <button key={answer.id} onClick={()=> handleAnswerButton(answer.correct, startTime, timeLimit)}>{answer.content}</button>
                    ))}
                    </div>
                </>
                )} */}

            </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: The setState method in React is asynchronous so there is no guarantee that the variables such as incorrect will have updated by the time the console.log method is run. It would be more preferable to have a useEffect to monitor any changes to incorrect, lives and guesses and run console.log there: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Also you would still have to use setLetters rather than push the letter directly on to the array i.e. setLetters(v => v.push(letter))